# Convering XLSX TO CSV in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I want to convert xlsx to csv using java but I don’t want to iterate and write into new csv, but I got idea from here we can use Aspose cell api

code is here:

```
workbook = new Workbook(dataPath + "5lakh_more.xlsx");

workbook.save(dataPath + "WorkbookCSV.csv", SaveFormat.CSV);
```

it is working fine.

My question are:

1. is it open source and reliable because when I download the jar file it didn’t ask any licence?
2. if it is not open source, which one I have to use?

Comment: Have you looked in the jar?  Have you tried google?  You're sorta asking people to do research for you, which isn't really what SO is for.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

1 - You can find License information for Aspose here:
http://www.aspose.com/corporate/purchase/policies/License-Types/default.aspx

2 - Use Apache POI, I think is the most used library for this porpouse (https://poi.apache.org/)